# C++ printf printing doubles reads as 0

Tags: c++, double, printf, cout, scientific-notation

So I want to use printf so that I can make columns line up but printf can't seem to print doubles that need scientific notation. It just comes out as a 0 but with cout it comes out fine. 'in' and 'fn' are structs 'x' 'y' and 'z' are doubles

Code

```
printf("Facet Normal: %lf %15lf %15lf\n", in->fn.x, in->fn.y, in->fn.z);
cout << "cout test: " << in->fn.x << endl;
```

Output

```
Facet Normal: -0.000000       -0.894426        0.447215
cout test: -9.6137e-08
```

I can't seem to get printf to work correctly. I had the entire function working correctly with cout but like I said, I'd like things to line up niftily.

**Edit:**

As Oli said, using %e does get it to print correctly. By using %e throughout though it puts everything in scientific notation and a lot of the numbers in the data set don't in reality really need it. Cout seems to convert between %lf and %e as needed. Is there an easy way to get printf to get this behavior as well?

**Answer:**

> %f is for both float and double (since float arguments are promoted to double); 
>   %lf is for long double. f prints with no exponent, e prints with an exponent, and 
>   g uses whichever looks better (following specific rules). 
>   –  Keith Thompson

%g gets the exact behavior I was looking for!

Comment: Use `%e` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: As you are using C++, it is better to use the C++ iostream, rather than stdio.h: that is more like C code

Comment: `%f` is for both `float` and `double` (since `float` arguments are promoted to `double`); `%lf` is for `long double`. `f` prints with no exponent, `e` prints with an exponent, and `g` uses whichever looks better (following specific rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to get the "best" formatting (which is the default for `std::ostream`): you can use `%g` (`%Lg` for `long double`) to have the formatting function decide how the values should be formatted. There are four format specifiers:

1. `%f` for fixed point notation (the format used by `std::fixed` for streams).
2. `%e` for scientific formatting (the format used by `std::scientific` for streams).
3. `%g` for the "best" version of fixed and scientific (the default for streams and since C++11 `std::defaultfloat`).
4. `%a` for an exact/hex representation of the floating point number (since C++11 `std::hexfloat`).

The formatting flags can used both in lowercase and uppercase to indicate whether any characters should be lowercase or uppercase (e.g. `e` vs. `E`). Note that the `l` length specifier is actually not relevant for the floating point formatting. You might need to use `L`, though, when formatting `long double`

Answer (score 3):

As the [`std::printf()` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) says, just use `%e`:

```
std::printf( "One double in decimal scientific notation! %e" , my_double );
```

But the correct C++ way is to use `std::cout` and some manipulators, [`std::scientific`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) in this case:

```
std::cout << "One double in decimal scientific notation!" << std::scientific << my_double;
```

Note that the format of `std::cout` forms part of its state, that is, you only have to configure it once, the format is applied to any output operation after the setting, and before other format change:

```
std::cout << std::scientific;

std::cout << std::pow( 10.0 , 10.0 ) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::pow( 10.0 , 20.0 ) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::pow( 10.0 , 30.0 ) << std::endl;
```

> 1e11
>   1e21
>   1e31

Comment: Please people, when downvote write a comment. I don't understand why this has a downvote

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the output from std::cout, use setw() and setfill().
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/

You can also set the precision, etc.  I will leave that to you to explore.